# Cómo repetir un ciclo while en java

Tags: java, while

quiero que me vuelva a preguntar la condición para entrar o salir del while pero no estaría encontrando la forma. Hasta ahora tengo esto.

```
    System.out.println("¿Agregar producto? S/N");
    respuesta = scan.nextLine();
        
    
    
    while (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s"));
    { 
    System.out.println("Descripcion Prod");
        descripcionProd = scan.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Cantidad Prod");
        cantidProd = scan.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Precio unitario Prod");
        precioProd = scan.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: ¿No funcionaría si simplemente copias las dos primeras líneas dentro del while?

Answer (score 3):

Aqui hay una cosa a notar, entonces primero te muestro:
tu línea `while (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s"));` no hace lo que pretendes porque el `;` que tenes justo después del último paréntesis indica que la instrucción termina. Se que pretendías hacer un while con un cuerpo de mas de una línea, es solamente mistyping.

Ahora, respecto a tu pregunta creo entender que quieres que te pregunte nuevamente `¿Agregar producto? S/N` entonces deberias:

```java
while (true)
{
   System.out.println("¿Agregar producto? S/N");
   respuesta = scan.nextLine();    
   if (!respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
      break;

   System.out.println("Descripcion Prod");
   descripcionProd = scan.nextLine(); 
   System.out.println("Cantidad Prod");
   cantidProd = scan.nextInt();
    
   System.out.println("Precio unitario Prod");
   precioProd = scan.nextInt();
}
```

**Edit 09/06/2021**

De acuerdo a lo discutido en los comentarios, edito la respuesta. Para evitar el problema salto de instrucción `nextLine` agrega un `nextLine` depués del último `nextInt()`. Esto es porque el `nextInt` no consume el caracter fin de línea, con lo que este queda en el buffer, y es leido por el inmediato `nextLine` lo que produce un efecto de salto de instrucción.

```java
while (true)
{
   System.out.println("¿Agregar producto? S/N");
   respuesta = scan.nextLine();    
   if (!respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
      break;

   System.out.println("Descripcion Prod");
   descripcionProd = scan.nextLine(); 
   System.out.println("Cantidad Prod");
   cantidProd = scan.nextInt();
    
   System.out.println("Precio unitario Prod");
   precioProd = scan.nextInt();
   scan.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Intenté de una forma parecida. Probé con lo que me dijiste pero me cuando lo corro pasa esto: Cantidad Prod
4
Precio unitario Prod
4
¿Agregar producto? S/N
*************************************************************************************
ingresarFecha(scan)
Nombre: k
Domicilio: j
*************************************************************************************

Me imprime la pregunta pero no me deja contestarla y se corre todo lo que resta del código (se imprime un ticket).

Comment: Cuando combinas `nextLines` con `nextInt` tenes que tener presente que `nextInt` no consume el caracter de fin de linea. Por tanto el siguiente `nextLine` si lo hace, entonces la reaccion es como si presionaras Enter; el efecto es como que se saltara la instrucción. Me temo que para evitarlo, tendras que hacer un "dummy" `nextLine` antes del real.

Comment: Buenísimo! ese ultimo me funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tomando la respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/460662/193364
He agregado la opción que sólo acepte las opciones de teclado (S/N) y sus respectivas minúsculas.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        while (leerRespuesta().equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
          Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Descripcion Prod");
          String descripcionProd = scan.nextLine();

          System.out.println("Cantidad Prod");
          int cantidProd = scan.nextInt();

          System.out.println("Precio unitario Prod");
          int precioProd = scan.nextInt();
        }

  }

  public static String leerRespuesta() {
    Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);    
    String leer;
    do{
        System.out.println("¿Agregar producto? S/N");
        leer=scan.nextLine();        
        
        if(!leer.equalsIgnoreCase("s")&&!leer.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
            System.out.println("Ingresar sólo las teclas (S/N)");
        }
    }while(!leer.equalsIgnoreCase("s")&&!leer.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
    
    return leer;
  }
```

Comment: Estar declarando `scanner` cada que se llama la función y cada que se hace una iteración en el `while` consume bastantes recursos; además como la mayoría de la gente, no estás cerrando el scanner (que es un *InputStream*), recuerda que es importantísimo pues cada que abres una instancia le estás solicitando al sistema recursos que no estás liberando.